# Can TypeScript express subtype polymorphism for statics on a class

Tags: typescript, types, polymorphism

Im looking a way to write an implementation in ts able to deny some statements with lookup typings

Having this implementation:

```
function animalDecorator <O extends propertyof Animal>(property: O) {
// should allow only properties from
// a class that extends from Animal

}

class Animal { }

class Cat extends Animal {
  static claws: any
}

class Stone {
  static shape: any
}
```

Then, typing this code, only first statement should be valid

```
animalDecorator(Cat.claws) //allow
animalDecorator(Stone.shape) //deny
```

Comment: What's your question? This isn't very clear.

Comment: I want typescript compiler to restrict function argument to be a 'property of a class that extends from A' Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that, you don't even pass the class to the function, how could the compiler enforce such a thing?

Comment: Ok, so if I pass the class to the funciton could be posible?

Comment: Im trying to do this with a decorator factory, which receives the target class, but not in the same signature btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `typeof` operator to get the type of the static side of a class.

In other words, you can declare your function as

```
function animalDecorator(target: typeof Animal, property: any) { /*...*/ }
```

If you wanted to use the type of `target` somehow, you could use generics:

```
function animalDecorators<T extends typeof Animal>(target: T, property: any): T { /*...*/ }
```

Lastly, there's no way to restrict values from arbitrary places, but you can restrict your function to only property names such as the following:

```
function animalDecorators<T extends typeof Animal>(target: T, property: keyof T) { /*...*/ }
```

So that you can write `animalDecorator(Cat, "claws")` but not `animalDecorator(Cat, "shape")`.

Comment: But I have to include target within the arguments? :( this is mandatory? Check last edit, thanks

Comment: If you want inference to occur, yes, but you can omit it and force users to explicitly specify it. I've updated my answer.